# Как искать файлы по размеру, и во вложенных папках?

Tags: java, файлы

Есть код, он проверяет указанную директорию и ищет в ней заданный файл по названию, как можно доработать этот код, что бы он искал файлы не по имени, а по их размеру (в байтах), и не только в указанной папке, но и в папках которые в этой папке.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
    {
        File directory = new File("C:\\Users\\excit\\Desktop");

        String[] flist = directory.list();
        int flag = 0;
        if (flist == null) {
            System.out.println("Empty directory.");
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++) {
                String filename = flist[i];
                if (filename.equalsIgnoreCase("pom.xml")) {
                    System.out.println(filename + " found");
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса `File` есть перегруженный метод `list`, принимающий параметром реализацию интерфейса `FilenameFilter`. Таким образом Вы можете отфильтровать результаты поиска по нужным критериям. Например:

```java
public class Main {

    public static final int MIN_LENGTH = 5;
    public static final String NAME_TO_SEARCH = "pom.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File directory = new File("C:\\Users");
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            String[] fileList = directory.list((dir, name) -> {
                File file = (new File(dir + "\\" + name));
                return file.isFile() && file.length() >= MIN_LENGTH && name.equalsIgnoreCase(NAME_TO_SEARCH);
            });
            if (fileList != null) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(fileList).toArray()));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Ну а для поиска во вложенных папках - вынесите этот код из `psvm` в отдельный метод и либо дергайте его рекурсивно по условию `file.isDirectory()`, либо по этому же условию складывайте найденные папки в какую-нибудь коллекцию и потом ищите в них.

Comment: Да спасибо, но я имел в виду ни размер названия файла, а размер файла в байтах, т.е. что бы искать не по имени в этой папке, а по размеру

Comment: file.length() - это размер файла в байтах

Comment: не хочу показаться совсем труднодоходимым, но что значит psvm ?

Comment: public stattic void main(). Это "быстрый набор" в intellijIdea

Comment: Да, код работает, правда с поиском во всех подпапках я еще не разобрался, хотел спросить еще, а как сделать, что бы в консоль выводился не только список соответствующих файлов, но и размер каждого из них, это реально сделать?

Comment: `File file = (new File(dir + "\\" + name));` - в этой строке Вы получаете объект класса `File`. С ним можно делать все что хотите - посмотрите на этот класс, изучите его возможности